# Using android arrayadapter passing variables

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.PhoneLookup;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class Main extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener  {
final String [] MyName = new String [10];
int i=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contact_view);
        Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        while (people.moveToNext()){
            int NameIndex = people.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME);
            String Name = people.getString(NameIndex);
            MyName[i] = Name.toString();
            i++;        
        }

            setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, 
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.textView1,
                    MyName));
    }

            class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

                public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                        int textViewResourceId, Strings[] string) {
                    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, string);
                    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                }

                @Override
                public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater =  (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_view, parent,false);

                    ImageView iv = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                    TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    ToggleButton tb = (ToggleButton) row.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);

                    tv.setText(MyName[i]);

                    return row;
                }
        }
```

I am having trouble working with this. I am a beginner in android and java.
I want to pull out contact name information and place them inside a string array `MyName`
and then use the inflater to map each contact name to a textfield
in the xml file. I also have a toggle button and an image that I would like to use separately for each row. How can I do that?
And how can I fix this where the class `MyAdapter` is not accessible and is stating that it is undeclared
and the `setListAdapter` creation function is showing an error.

Multiple markers at this line

```
The type Main.MyAdapter is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String>
```

Comment: In `MyAdapter` constructor you are setting `List<String>` as last argument but during  `MyAdapter` object creation passing String Array

Comment: i have changed that to String[] String but the error is still the same
whenever i use the eclipse fix it removes the <String> and set it to MyAdapter only

Comment: I have tried to launch the application but there is an error and it is not working i do not understand why